# Print without scrolling down in python3 macos terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

I'm using a MacOS terminal at fullscreen, lets say there are theoretically a max of 5 lines in this terminal, and I have a list (nlst) of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and I print them using

```
print('\n'.join(nlst))
```

and it prints like this

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

and you have to scroll up to see the 1-5, how do I get it to print like

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and you have to scroll down to see the 6-10, the file is called test.py.

i have tried to use

```
python3 test.py | less
```

but this adds a weird thing at the top and I can't exit it, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim keybindings in less.

You can exit by pressing 'q'.

You can also see other commands in less by pressing 'h'.

Otherwise, you can pipe your output to head program

```
python3 test.py | head -n 5
```

This will print first five lines of your output

Comment: when I do that, I cant use time.sleep, and when I try to clear it, it doesnt clear